# someone is able to remote access my sony phone touchscreen even when in in airplane mode. how could that be possible?

Tags: wi-fi

My phone has been hacked. Through a hidden network the hacker seems to be accessing my touch screen remotely.
But this happens even in airplane mode. How to truly disable all network activity ?

Comment: Could you provide more information about "accessing my touch screen remotely"? What happened and what did you observe?

Comment: Yes please do provide some additional detail. Does this happen when at home, work or where?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that your phone has been hacked.

If the actions your phone is doing are random, you might be experiencing issues with the touchscreen or with its firmware. Consider factory resetting your phone and look if the problem does still exist.